# Android Emulator is not showing up after upgrading Android SDK

Tags: android

I have a problem. My AVD are working fine until I upgraded my SDK to 4.2.2. After a I clicked `Start` button of AVD manager its not showing up.  I tried to delete the device but I get an error msg `The Android Virtual Device 'Test Device 4' is currently running in an emulator and cannot be deleted`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

check the AVD file (emulator-user.ini) probably the coordinates are wrong reset them to 0. and then it will appear on your screen.

Comment: I did it and nothing happened.