# Android: Cannot start the emulator after upgrading sdk

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

Actually, I asked a question similar to this but I wasn't able to point out the main problem. [Android Emulator is not showing up after upgrading Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236727/android-emulator-is-not-showing-up-after-upgrading-android-sdk)

I had this problem after upgrading my android sdk from 4.1.2 (API 16) to 4.2.2 (API 17)

My emulator is not starting and I suspect the main reason is the upgrade to higher version of android sdk.

Idk what I did wrong but Im really having hard time figuring it out. I tried alot of suggestion such as checking the coordinates in the `emulator-user.ini` and deleting the device and creating a new one. So far nothing worked for me.

As of now, I have 2 sdk installed, 4.1.2(API 16) and 4.2.2(API 17) and some Extras such as `Google Play services`.

In the tools, I have `Android SDK Tools Rev. 21.1` and `Android SDK Platform-tools Rev. 16.0.2`

Im using elipse indigo and ubuntu 12.04.

As far as I can remember this is working fine until I upgraded the android sdk.

Please help me point out if there is something I did wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried starting it by itself? (the upper bar of Eclipse comes to mind). If that method doesn't work, it should at least give you some error screen and/or messages in the console you might be able to use.

Comment: @DigCamara Yeah I tried emulator -avd TestDevice and I got "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and also emulator -avd GoogleDevice and I got "PANIC: Could not open: GooleDevice".

Comment: I haven't had that problem myself, but googling "PANIC:"...etc. I came upon an answer right here. You might want to try some of the options listed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009872/android-eclipse-panic-could-not-open

Answer (score 1):

> As a work-around, you can define the environment variable
>   ANDROID_SDK_HOME to point to the directory containing your .android
>   directory. The emulator and SDK Manager will pick it up properly.
>
> Will look into this. There is likely a difference between the way the
>   SDK Manager and emulator pick up the user's directory when this
>   variable is not defined.

[From here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084)

There's [this method](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084#c19) as well:

> Open a command prompt in your user directory on C: (if you relocated
>   all your special windows folders to D: then their should only be a
>   hidden Appdata folder in your users C: folder). Use mklink program to
>   make a hard link to the .android directory on D:. So if user John Doe
>   move all his Users files from C:\Users to D: then the command to make
>   the directory junction would be:
>
> mklink /J "C:\Users\John Doe.android" "D:\John Doe.android"
>
> Now when the ADT plugin is trying to reference .android on C: NTFS
>   send th request to D: and the emulator starts correctly.

Comment: I tried it but in Ubuntu. I added ANDROID_SDK_HOME = /home/tom/android-sdk/ in my "/etc/environement" then followed the steps in eclipse.

Comment: And it didn't work? Sorry to hear that. I'll leave the answer there anyway, it might help someone else solve their problem. Unless you'd like to retag your question, of course.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. I'll try my very best to resolve this and put my answer to help others if ever I fix this.